# Using getline and istringstream to read from file is producing zeroes

Tags: c++, string, file-io

I have a text file that looks like so:

```
6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2
1 4
1 5
2 3
2 5
2 6
3 4
3 6
4 5
5 6
```

I use the following to read the lines of the file in to my variables and arrays:

```
//Read first line
if( std::getline(in, line))                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        std::istringstream iss(line);                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        while( iss >> a);                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    // read second line                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    int i = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    if( std::getline(in, line) )                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        std::istringstream iss(line);                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        while( iss >> b[i] )                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            ++i;                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    // read rest of file matrix                                                                                                                                                                               
    int x = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    while( !in.eof())                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        if( std::getline(in, line))                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            std::istringstream iss1(line);                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            while( iss1 >> c[x])                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                ++x;                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    }
```

In the code above `a` is an int, `b` and `c` are int arrays, `in` is an istream operator and `line` is a `std::string`. It seems to work fine however when I `std::cout` the variable and arrays I get the following:

```
6
1,2,3,4,5,6
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

For some reason array `c` seems to be filled with all zeroes instead of the data from the file. This is odd to me since I am reading the first two lines exactly the same way and they seemed to read in just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: what happens if you change the line `while(!in.eof())` to `while(in)` ?

Comment: @wilhelmtell Made the changes you suggested same result.

Comment: Works for me...  Is your data file and your code a copy-paste?

Comment: Are your arrays big enough? If not, maybe the `in` stream object is being corrupted. Also, basic debugging should give you an answer in no time - even good, old `printf()` debugging should zero you in pretty quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out and I figured I would post it here for future people. I ended up implementing the function below and it worked correctly.

```
// declare the variables to be used
    int a, b, c, d, e;
    std::string line;

    // open file for reading
    in.open(file);

    in >> a;
    std::cout << a << '\n';

    for(int i=0; i<a; ++i)
        in >> b

    in >> c;

    for(int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
    {    
        in >> d >> e;

        // push to vector here
    }

    in.close();
```